# Recover data from a bad sector hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, sector

I have a 2TB hard drive with 0% health and it contains a lot of bad sectors. When I attach the drive with the PC, it shows the data inside it, but I cannot copy it or open it, when i try to do this, my entire pc slows down and after few minutes hard drive disconnects from the pc. Is there any possible way to recover the data from the hard drive? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When the OS finds a bad sector the data is lost and is not recoverable. I am sorry. That's why you need to backup. Do you have an external drive or use the cloud? If not then I hope that you did not lose any important data. Always backup even on a good HDD. I would personally replace the HDD if you got a lot of bad sectors but a few is not a problem by that I mean a small amount of bad sectors like 1 bad sector. If there is a lot then replace it like 1000 bad sectors.

Read more:
A few bad sectors are not an issue but do check if the bad sectors are increasingly very fast as this will be telling you that your HDD will die soon.

Tip: Your hard drive could last 1 minute to 5 years depending on how well you treat your hard drive. It also depends on where you got the HDD from. So always back up.

A few bad sectors are no issue just check through over time. The bad sector is a part of your HDD that is damaged from physical or software issues. Physical such as dropping the HDD and software for an example you HDD is trying to write to that sector but you get a power cut. So just backup your stuff more often on an HDD that is having bad sectors.

A sector is a small space on the HDD that is 512 bytes per sector.

When the OS finds a bad sector the sector will no longer be used and data to the sector is lost.

You cant fix bad sectors because when you fix them. It will go bad again but one bad sector can still be used at its current state of health.

Update just wanted to add something:

Having bad sectors is a bad thing because you get lower performance, less storage space and if it increases in a short time then your disk is failing although a few are not a problem.

Do note that bad sectors can damage your file system or your boot sector. So you may need to reinstall the OS.

You most likely got nothing to worry about if you got less than 10 bad sectors although if it's 10 or more I would replace it.

Comment: Hope this help. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. My hard drive has 250 bad sectors and they are not increasing. The health of my hard drive 0%. Whenever I attach my hard drive to my computer, it shows up for some time and when I open it or try to copy any file, it freezes there and then it disappear. Is there any way to recover the data?

Comment: @AHMYTech. Hi. 250 bad sectors is a big number and I would not trust this drive. But it may last for a few more years but I recommend getting it replaced. You can't really fix bad sectors or recover from them but if there is data not in a bad sector then yes. You could clone your drive to a healthy one. Or upload your files to the cloud. Overall you can use this drive but for non-important data. When replacing the HDD make sure it is the right size such as 2.5 inches and the right type such as SATA. If under warranty give it in they replace it for you. :) Hope this helped.